# Element-wise multiply a dense vector with each row of a sparse matrix in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, sparse-matrix

Suppose I have a sparse matrix

```
A = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,0],[1,1],[1,2]], values=[1,1,1], 
                dense_shape=[2,3])
```

and a dense vector

```
B = tf.constant([4,3,5])
```

The shape of matrix A and vector B are `(2,3)`, `(1,3)` respectively. I would like to element-wise multiply B with each row of A. The expected result is another sparse matrix, say

```
C = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,0],[1,1],[1,2]], values=[4,3,5], 
                dense_shape=[2,3])
```

I know it would be relatively easy if `A` is a dense matrix, but the dense size of `A` is extremely large and most of the elements in `A` are zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiplying with an asterisk `*` works.

```
tf.reduce_all(tf.sparse.to_dense(A * B) == tf.sparse.to_dense(C))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=True>
```

Btw, `B` has shape `(3,)`, not `(1, 3)`

This is the result of this operation:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[4, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 5]])>
```

You could also have done this manually, but keep an eye on the broadcasting rules:

```
tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices=A.indices, values=A.values * B, 
                       dense_shape=A.dense_shape)
```